# Font name has '*' added and type has a pink background in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, font-management

I've been  using Illustrator for a short time and just now installed some fonts on my computer to use them in my project, only Illustrator doesn't recognize them. The background is getting pink.

And the sources bar, they are with a "*"

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: It means the font is **not** installed (or active) on your system.

Comment: I think not, because I installed the yes sources in my system

Comment: What are the font type or extension? Also, I see you seem to have the issue with Helvetica Neue which can simply be conflicting with the default one in the system's font folder.

Comment: Hello augustoppimenta, welcome to GD.SE. This is an English-language site, so please refrain from adding content in another language. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

If you are confident that you have selected a font that you have installed on the machine, you may have a font style selected that isn't available. For example, I see that the style you have set is "Normal", but it may need to be "Regular". This can happen usually when you switch from one font to another and the assigned style isn't present in the new font.